# "SyntaxError is already defined" error with Psych

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych

When trying to run `rails server` or `rails console` I get the following error:

```
$ bundle exec rails server
/path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.rb:1:in `require': SyntaxError is already defined (NameError)
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails.rb:10:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

First line in `/path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.rb` is `require 'psych.so'`. I use ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.14, psych version 2.0.5 is setup in `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: This is a double-load of the `psych` library. The gem can conflict with the built-in one if the bundled one gets loaded first. Do you still have the problems with Ruby 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: I've not tried with Ruby 2.0 or 2.1, but I've just ran `bundle install --no-deployment` instead of `bundle install`, then my `rails ...` commands now work.

Answer (score 0):

> I use ruby 1.9.3

You sure about that?

```
/path/to/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.rb
```

Might want to make sure your environment is how you expect it.  Is this a new problem?  What changed since it used to work?  We have practically no information to go off of.

Comment: From `/path/to/projet` `ruby -v` returns `ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]`, and `which ruby` returns `/Users/florent2/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. It's a new project for me, it's the first time I install it on my machine. Let me know which kind of other information you need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 will always report 1.9.1 in the path for obscure, unspecified reasons.